# How can we solve the following non homogeneous laplace equation 2D?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

let we have the following non homogeneous laplace equation 2D $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=q(x,y)$$ where $0<x<a$ and $0<y<b$

with the conditions

$u(x,0)=f(x)$ where $0<x<a$

and

$u(x,b)=g(x)$ where $0<x<a$

and

$u(0,y)=0$ where $0<y<b$

and

$u(a,y)=0$ where $0<y<b$

find the following of this problem by using variables separation

Comment: Well, what have you done so far?

Comment: @JasonBorn where should i start ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Since you didn't know how to begin, I will help you get started. In particular, you have the boundary value problem

$$\begin{cases}u_{xx}(x,y)+u_{yy}(x,y)=q(x,y),&x\in[0,a],y\in[0,b],
\\
u(x,0)=f(x),&x\in[0,a],
\\
u(x,b)=g(x),&x\in[0,a],
\\
u(0,y)=u(a,y)=0,&y\in[0,b].
\end{cases}$$

To solve this via separation of variables, we look for solutions of the form $u(x,y)=\boldsymbol{X}(x)\boldsymbol{Y}(y)$.

Firstly, for the *homogeneous* Laplace equation

$$v_{xx}(x,y)+v_{yy}(x,y)=X''(x)Y(y)+X(x)Y''(y)=0$$

we may deduce that

$$\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}=\pm\lambda^2,\qquad\lambda>0.$$

Now, you can solve the eigenvalue problem

$$\begin{cases}X''(x)\pm\lambda^2 X(x)=0,
\\
Y''(y)\mp\lambda^2 Y(y)=0,\end{cases}$$
in order to determine $v(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$.

Then you have $q(x,y)=v_{xx}(x,y)+v_{yy}(x,y)$ and you can probably solve from there.

Comment: i have just add two conditions i forgot to add them before

Comment: sir can you help me more?

Comment: what should i do then ?

Comment: @spacetime2018 Which part do you need help with?

Comment: the last one how can find $u$

Comment: @spacetime2018 See these notes (specifically the first part): http://www.math.psu.edu/wysocki/M412/Notes412_10.pdf.

Comment: i need exactly the same problem here

Comment: I could not understand anything please explain sir

Comment: @spacetime2018 Which part would you like me to explain?

Comment: The last one how can complete $q(x,y)=v_{xx}(x,y)+v_{yy}(x,y)$